# Loading a CVS file where the data is all in one column

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I am importing a CSV file that contains data which is all in a single column (the TXT file has the data separated by ";"

Is there anyway to get the data to load into Anaconda (using Panda) so that it is in separate columns, or can it be manipulated afterwards into columns?

The data can be found at the following web-address (this is data about sunspots):

http://www.sidc.be/silso/INFO/snmtotcsv.php

From this website http://www.sidc.be/silso/datafiles

I have managed to do this so far:

## Start code by loading the Panda command set

from pandas import *

```
#Initial setup commands
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', FutureWarning)
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.grid'] = True # show gridlines by default
%matplotlib inline
from scipy.stats import spearmanr

#load data from CSV file
startdata = read_csv('SN_m_tot_V2.0.csv',header=None)
startdata = startdata.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer elsewhere; the lines of code that takes into account the lack of column headings AND the separator being s semi-colon is:

```
colnames=['Year','Month','Year (fraction)','Sunspot number','Std dev.','N obs.','Provisional']
ssdata=read_csv('SN_m_tot_V2.0.csv',sep=';',header=None,names=colnames)
```